# Service invoked too many times for one day: email with only 19 emails sent on a Time Trigger

Tags: email, google-apps-script, quota

I have looked over all the MailApp limitations over at:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas

The company I work for has their own Google domain and should qualify for over 1,500 emails a day. I am getting this error no where near that number.

Upon writing this code and debugging at the start of the day:

```
var y  = MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();
```

It appears to say I have a maximum of 100 emails a day from the MailApp command. If my company is using Google's services, why do I qualify for only 100 emails instead of 1,500?

Furthermore, why is the service being blocked if I send significantly under 100 emails?

Comment: Try using Gmail.

Comment: You should be able to send to 1,500 recipients a day, unless the G Suite account hasn't gone past the first billing cycle.  If the account has fewer than 6 users, then the wait period can be longer than the first billing cycle.  Also, the quota is "Email ***recipients*** per day" not emails per day.  One email can have multiple recipients.  5 emails sent to 10 addresses count as 50 total recipients.

Answer (score 0):

### You question can be answered with the following information

- [Description of the `getRemainingDailyQuota()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app):

  - Returns the number of remaining emails a user can send for the rest of the day. Quotas are based on the **number of email recipients**.
- [Email recipients per day](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas):

[image]
[image]

> This means that if your company's Google Domain is new, you might be
>   temporary limited to 100 email **recipients** per day, which can result in less than 100 **emails** per day.

Comment: Ziganotschka, your answers to Script Editor questions on here are always very helpful. However, in this case, I do not believe you're right as I send only one recipient per email. I should probably have specified that in the question, but me resorting to stackoverflow to answer my question should indicate the solution wasn't that simple. Thanks.